# Android worker gets cancelled no cause shown

Tags: android, android-workmanager

```
Work [ id=ab50e634-d315-4566-acc2-fe146a7366e2, tags={ in.offline.usecase.Upload****s$Worker, upload/***/now/* } ] was cancelled
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.cancellationExceptionWithCause(AbstractFuture.java:1184)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:514)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:475)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper$2.run(WorkerWrapper.java:284)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Why work manager developer cannot show the cause for cancellation, this issue is around a year now, they are providing foreground support but not fixing the basic issue.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem ?

Comment: @AhlemJarrar nope

Comment: Is just so random, I thought that only one of my works was being cancelled, but all my works are being cancelled without explanation to debug. Have to ask my users to close and open the app again for the workers to `work`, randomly. This is a bummer.

Answer (score 1):

It could be another service your app is running that is causing it to cancel.